# Bash: Get modified `ls`-like output (multiple entries per line)

Tags: bash, multiple-columns, ls

When you call `ls` without additional options on the command line, you get multiple entries per line.

Contrived example:

```
$ ls mydir/*.tar.gz
mydir/foo.tar.gz        mydir/bar.tar.gz        mydir/baz.tar.gz
```

But if you want to *modify* the output in some way, you get one entry per line:

```
$ ls mydir/*.tar.gz | sed "s/\.tar\.gz//g"
mydir/foo
mydir/bar
mydir/baz
```

With many entries, that becomes cumbersome -- I would like the multiple, aligned columns back.

I was trying to come up with something along the lines of `find mydir -name "*.tar.gz" -printf ...`, or `... -exec ...`, or even (yuk!) `for file in $(find ...)`, but anything I could come up with reeks of being really inelegant (think counter variables, taking modulo and just guessing terminal width...).

Is there some elegant way to get a couple of filenames in a multiple-column output like with vanilla `ls`, after having tinkered with them (via e.g. `sed`, `basename` etc.)?

Comment: Since it's easy to miss: the key phrase is "after having tinkered with them", which implies that columnating must occur _later_, _after_ modification of `ls`'s output, so `ls` _itself by definition can NOT provide it_. The accepted answer accounts for that (by offering a generic columnation solution), while other answers here cover how to get `ls` _itself_ to columnate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The (surprisingly named) `column` command will do what you want.

```
ls | column -c 80
```

This will display the output in columns for an 80-wide display. You might have to wait for the output as it has to figure out the width of the items before it can format anything.

It will work with any command.

You can find your column width with the `COLUMNS` environment variable (this might depend on your shell - type `set` to see a list of variables and figure it out), or using the `tput cols` command.

Comment: This looks promising... any way to determine the *real* (current) terminal width beforehand?

Answer (score 4):

`ls -C` forces the multi-column output even when the output is directed away from the console.

Comment: Somehow this seems fickle: Using real-world paths / filenames, when I call `ls -C` without doing anything to the output, I get the terminal filled to full width. As soon as I pipe the output somewhere, it seems to assume a much smaller terminal window... and if the postprocessing *shortens* each entry, that is not (cannot be) taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

**Update** and **disclaimer**:

- This answer does NOT work for the OP, because he wants to *modify* `ls` output first, and *then* columnate it; thus, columnation must be applied in a *separate* pass, *later*, which is what the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28966772/45375) offers via `column -c <n>`.
- This answer only works if you want to use columnated `ls` output *as is*.

  - Aside from that, it provides some potentially interesting background information on how `ls` decides how to format its output and what max. line width it assumes.

---

To build on [rojomoke's promising answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28966653/45375), which points out that `-C` explicitly requests multi-column output from `ls`:

**tl;dr**

To **emulate `ls`'s multi-column *terminal* output** when **sending something to a file or through a pipe *using the current terminal's max. line width*** (number of single-character display columns), use **`COLUMNS=$(tput cols) ls -C`**; e.g.:

```
COLUMNS=$(tput cols) ls -C | cat  # `| cat` is an example command to show pipe behavior
```

<sup>Obviously, you can also pick a fixed number independently of the current terminal; e.g., `COLUMNS=120 ls -C ...`</sup>

**Without the `COLUMNS=...` prefix, columnation occurs based on a max. line width of `80`**, irrespective of the terminal window's actual width.

---

<sup>Note: The following is in part speculative. Do let me know if I'm wrong.</sup>

`ls`, when **outputting to a *terminal***:

- produces columnated (multi-column) output by default (`-C` is implied)
- determines the terminal's max. line width *itself*.<sup>[1]</sup>

By contrast, when `ls`'s stdout is **connected to a *pipe or output file***, it

- defaults to line-by-line output (`-1` is implied)
- when `-C` is specified, it takes the line width from the `COLUMNS` *environment* variable (NOT the *shell* variable); if there's no such variable, the default is `80`.

In `bash` shells, `$COLUMNS` is typically a *shell* variable set in the *interactive shell only*, not an *environment* variable - in other words: `$COLUMNS` is defined, but not *exported*.

**To get `ls` to respect the `$COLUMNS` variable, you must define it as an *environment* variable.**

The cleanest approach is to prepend an **ad-hoc, command-local environment-variable definition** to the invocation of `ls` (the general pattern is: `<envVar>=<value> <commmand> ...`):

Since `tput cols` returns the line width for the current terminal, we get:

```
COLUMNS=$(tput cols) ls -C ...
```

<sup>`tput cols` also works in scripts, so it's the robust approach; interactively, the seemingly pointless command `COLUMNS=$COLUMNS ls -C` would work too.</sup>

Note that `ls` will even respect the `COLUMNS` environment variable when outputting to the *terminal*.

---

<sup>[1] That is, it doesn't *need* environment variable `COLUMNS`, but respects it, if defined. Note that a (non-exported) *shell* variable named `COLUMNS` - as is the typical case in interactive shells - is *ignored*.</sup>

Comment: As I commented to rojomoke, the inherent problem here is that the formatting is done *before* you're modifying the output. If, for example, the modification is to remove path components (making each entry shorter), your output will not use the full terminal width. If the modification does *irregular* changes to the length of your entries, your output will lose formatting. Very interesting read, but rghome nailed the solution I think. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar: You're right - I missed the part about wanting to format _after_ modifications. So, rghome's answer is indeed the right solution (and even though it doesn't matter in the end, I'm glad he changed the `find` command to `ls` to avoid a distraction) - I'll add a disclaimer to my answer and leave it, because I too think the behavior is interesting.

Comment: With the disclaimer, +1 for detail. Thanks for your time.